Cox Regression with multiple predictors; How to avoid NA result on last predictor
I got a problem with the results of my cox model in R. Anytime I put in multiple predictors, the last one (alphabetically) turns out with NA's and I don't know how to fix it. I tried with various variables (continuous and categorical as well. I also changed the alphabetical order to exclude that there is a problem with the data of the predictor.
Can somebody help me out?
Thanks in advance!
This is my code and the outcome:
cfit <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ a + b + c  , data=xdata) ; cfit

Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ a + b + c, data = xdata)

coef exp(coef)  se(coef)      z        p

a -0.002962  0.997043  0.001423 -2.081   0.0374

b  0.004366  1.004376  0.000861  5.071 3.95e-07

c        NA        NA  0.000000     NA       NA

Likelihood ratio test=19.63  on 2 df, p=5.476e-05
n= 374, number of events= 374 

All numeric variables used in this example are measures of depths in meters w/ no NA's in the dataset
a <- xdata$Depth_min  ; xdata <- cbind(xdata, a) ; xdata <- xdata[complete.cases(a), ] ; name_a <- "Minimum Depth [m]" ; rm(a) ; print(xdata$a)
b <- xdata$Depth_mean ; xdata <- cbind(xdata, b) ; xdata <- xdata[complete.cases(b), ] ; name_b <- "Mean Depth [m]"    ; rm(b) ; print(xdata$b)
c <- xdata$Depth_max  ; xdata <- cbind(xdata, c) ; xdata <- xdata[complete.cases(c), ] ; name_c <- "Maximum Depth [m]" ; rm(c) ; print(xdata$c)

Data and Context: I am using SA to explore differences in the first Detection/Publication of a species. The Year of Publication is my event ("Death"). With the Cox-Model I am trying to find which variables influence an earlier detection of a species. I am using: Bodysize, Min/Mean/Max_Depth, Substrate, Life_habit, Professional Collector,
> dput(head(xdata))
structure(list(No. = c(260, 356, 1, 318, 256, 387), 
Class = c("Malacostraca", "Malacostraca", "Copepoda", "Malacostraca", "Malacostraca", "Malacostraca"), 
Order = c("Decapoda", "Decapoda", "Calanoidea", "Decapoda", 
"Decapoda", "Stomatopoda"), 
Suborder = c("Dendrobranchiata", "Pleocyemata", NA, "Pleocyemata", "Dendrobranchiata", "Unipeltata"), 
Infraorder = c(NA, "Caridea", NA, "Brachyura", NA, NA), 
Family = c("Luciferidae", "Palaemonidae", "Acartiidae", "Ocypodidae", "Penaeidae", "Squillidae"), 
Genus = c("Lucifer", "Palaemon", "Acartia (Acartia)", "Ocypode", "Parapenaeus", "Squilla"), 
Species = c("typus", "adspersus", "negligens", "cursor", "longirostris", "mantis"),   
Year_publ_first = c(1898, 1927, 1929, 1929, 1931, 1931), 
Linnean = c(1758, 1758, 1758, 1758, 1758, 1758), 
Survival_Time = c(140, 169, 171, 171, 173, 173), 
Survival_Status = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
TS_comb = c(10, 21, 1.27, 35, 86, 165), 
Depth_min = c(45, 0, 0, 0, 1, NA), 
Depth_max = c(137, 60, 200, 0, 180, NA),
Depth_mean = c(91, 30, 100, 0, 90.5, NA),  
Substratum = c("pelagic", "soft", NA, "soft", "soft", NA), 
Life_habit = c("pelagic", "epifaunal", "pelagic", "epifaunal", "epifaunal", "epifaunal"),
Coll_Professional = c("yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", "yes"), 
`trophic level` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))


Welcome to SO, Sarah!  This looks like an over-parameterisation problem - that is, your predictor c is a linear combination of a and b .  For example, if a is an indicator for "Age <18", b for "Age between 18 and 55" and c for "Over 55".  But without sight of (some of) your data, we can't be sure.  By the way, most people think it's wise to avoid using the names of R functions (such as c) as variable and column names.  It leads to confusion and possibly errors.

Hi, thanks for the advice! I will keep it in mind! I edited my question above so you can see what kind of data I am using.
I read about that maybe the coxph() uses the last variable (c in this case) as a reference variable?
Beyond that even if my variables are: size + depths + year + ... the last one will always be like c in the example above.

Sarah, we still can't see your actual data.  Please add the results of dput(xdata) to your question.  Or, if xdata is large, dput(head(xdata)).  If you opt for the latter, please check that the subset of the data you provide allows us to reproduce your problem.

Ciao Limey, I added the data. I hope it can bring you some insight.

I suspect you have summarised your original data and have only two observations of depth (for each species?) in your original data.  There is perfect colinearity between your three depth measurements and your model is overparameterised.  As a result, whichever effect you add to your model last will be unestimable.  This is unavoidable given the (small) dataset you have provided.  The problem has nothing to do with the alphabetical order of the names of the terms.
To demonstrate the colinarity, consider:
xdata %>% 
  select(Depth_min, Depth_mean, Depth_max) %>% 
  mutate(Check = 2 * Depth_mean - (Depth_max + Depth_min))
# A tibble: 6 × 4
  Depth_min Depth_mean Depth_max Check
      <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
1        45       91         137     0
2         0       30          60     0
3         0      100         200     0
4         0        0           0     0
5         1       90.5       180     0
6        NA       NA          NA    NA

